# jQuery animating height show/hide getting stuck

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I think I know why this is happening but I am not sure of the best way to tackle it. Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xetCd/4/) you can refer to.

If you attempt to open and close a sub-menu in the jsFiddle (Click the + icon next to any link) and then open it again before it has fully closed it will become stuck. Now open the menu and attempt to open one of it's child sub-menu's and you will see that it's parent doesn't expand to accommodate it.

I believe this problem is caused because during the `hide` procedure `jQuery` applies an inline height to the element and if you attempt to open it before it finishes animating it assumes that it is the final height of the element.

I considered storing the height of each element at the very start and using that to animate towards, however the problem with this approach is that menus with sub-menus height changes all the time depending on whether it's sub-menus are open and this value is never a constant.

Is there anyway to tell jQuery to ignore the element's inline height and calculate what it's true height should be?

Here is the jQuery used, for the HTML and CSS please see the jsFiddle as they are rather lengthy:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var legacyMode = $('html').hasClass('oldie');
    var titles = {normal: "Show sub-topics", active: "Hide sub-topics"};

    var sub_sections = $('ul#map li:has(ul.child)');

    sub_sections.each(function() {
        if (!$(this).find('li.active').length && !$(this).hasClass('active')) {
            var toggle = $('<a class="toggle" href="#"></a>').attr('title', titles.normal).insertBefore($(this).children('ul.child'));
            var child = $(this).children('ul.child').hide();
            toggle.data('container', this);
        }
    });

    $('a.toggle').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).siblings('ul.child');
        if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            toggleDisplay(target, false);
            $(this).removeClass('active').attr('title', titles.normal);
        } else {
            toggleDisplay(target, true);
            $(this).addClass('active').attr('title', titles.active);
        }
        function toggleDisplay(target, on) {
            var mode = (on) ? "show" : "hide";
            if (!legacyMode) {
                target.stop(true, false).animate({height: mode, opacity: mode}, 500);
            } else {
                // Omits opacity to avoid using proprietary filters in legacy browsers
                target.stop(true, false).animate({height: mode}, 500);
            }
        }
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I made a working solution... it isn't quite as straight forward as I would of hoped but anyway here is the working code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var legacyMode = $('html').hasClass('oldie');
    var titles = {normal: "Show sub-topics", active: "Hide sub-topics"};

    var sub_sections = $('ul#map li:has(ul.child)');

    sub_sections.each(function() {
        if (!$(this).find('li.active').length && !$(this).hasClass('active')) {
            var child = $(this).children('ul.child');
            if (!legacyMode) {
                child.css({height : '0px', opacity : 0, display: 'none'});
            } else {
                // Omits opacity to avoid using proprietary filters in legacy browsers
                child.css({height : '0px', display: 'none'});
            }
            var toggle = $('<a class="toggle" href="#"></a>').attr('title', titles.normal).insertBefore(child);
            toggle.data('container', this);
        }
    });

    $('a.toggle').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).siblings('ul.child');
        if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            toggleDisplay(target, false);
            $(this).removeClass('active').attr('title', titles.normal);
        } else {
            toggleDisplay(target, true);
            $(this).addClass('active').attr('title', titles.active);
        }
        function toggleDisplay(target, on) {
            var targetOpacity = 0;
            var targetHeight = 0;
            if (on) { 
                // Get height of element once expanded by creating invisible clone
                var clone = target.clone().attr("id", false).css({visibility:"hidden", display:"block", position:"absolute", height:""}).appendTo(target.parent());
                targetHeight = clone.height();
                targetOpacity = 1;
                console.log(clone.height());
                clone.remove();
                target.css({display : 'block'});
            }
            if (!legacyMode) {
                target.stop(true, false).animate({height: targetHeight + "px" , opacity: targetOpacity}, {
                    duration: 500,
                    complete: function() {
                        if (on) {
                            $(this).css({height : '', opacity : ''});
                        } else {
                            $(this).css({display : 'none'});
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                // Omits opacity to avoid using proprietary filters in legacy browsers
                target.stop(true, false).animate({height: targetHeight + "px"}, {
                    duration: 500,
                    complete: function() {
                        if (on) {
                            $(this).css({height : ''});
                        } else {
                            $(this).css({display : 'none'});
                        }
                    }
                });           
            }
        }
    });
});​
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/xetCd/24/ (Click any combination of toggle's in any order any amount of times and it should stay smooth).

Tested with: IE7, IE8 (set `var legacyMode` to `true` for best results), Firefox 15, Chrome 23

How does it work? Well I no longer use the `show` and `hide` animation targets as these are not flexible enough. For this reason I have to hide the `ul`s at initialization a little differently:

```
var child = $(this).children('ul.child');
if (!legacyMode) {
    child.css({height : '0px', opacity : 0, display: 'none'});
} else {
    // Omits opacity to avoid using proprietary filters in legacy browsers
    child.css({height : '0px', display: 'none'});
}
var toggle = $('<a class="toggle" href="#"></a>').attr('title', titles.normal).insertBefore(child);​
```

Now on to the juicy bit, how to calculate the target height of the element when it could be at any stage of the animation and have any amount of sub-menu's open or closed. I got around this by creating a `visibility : hidden` duplicate of the element and forcing it to take up it's regular height, I also gave it `position : absolute` so that it doesn't appear to take up any space in the document. I grab it's height and delete it:

```
var targetOpacity = 0;
var targetHeight = 0;
if (on) { 
    // Get height of element once expanded by creating invisible clone
    var clone = target.clone().attr("id", false).css({visibility:"hidden", display:"block", position:"absolute", height:""}).appendTo(target.parent());
    targetHeight = clone.height();
    targetOpacity = 1;
    console.log(clone.height());
    clone.remove();
    target.css({display : 'block'});
}​
```

Then I animate it and make sure to reset the `display` and remove the `height` (so sub-menu's can expand their parent) properties:

```
if (!legacyMode) {
    target.stop(true, false).animate({height: targetHeight + "px" , opacity: targetOpacity}, {
        duration: 500,
        complete: function() {
            if (on) {
                $(this).css({height : '', opacity : ''});
            } else {
                $(this).css({display : 'none'});
            }
        }
    });
} else {
    // Omits opacity to avoid using proprietary filters in legacy browsers
    target.stop(true, false).animate({height: targetHeight + "px"}, {
        duration: 500,
        complete: function() {
            if (on) {
                $(this).css({height : ''});
            } else {
                $(this).css({display : 'none'});
            }
        }
    });           
}​
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because of the properties you're passing on the [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method, before `animate()`.

The second property in the method `stop(true, false)` specifies whether the animation should jump to the last frame or not. In you code, since it is `false`, it gets stuck at the stage the `click` is registered next on the anchor tag.

Change it to `.stop(true, true)` and it will work as expected!

Comment: Thanks but I wanted it to animate from the frame it ends on. Is this not possible?

Comment: In that case, you'll need to modify the code a bit. Add an `animating` class to the element before the animation process starts and remove it once it is done animating. Check to see if the element has the animating class and only run the show hide if it does not. Updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xetCd/7/

Comment: I think you misunderstood and that code presents some new problems especially in the usability department but +1 for the effort. I wan't it to function like `.stop(true, false)` but not get stuck. So it animates from whatever point the user decides to toggle it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem with jQuery 1.8.3, and found that upgrading to v1.12.2 fixed it.  For anyone else running into this, that may be a solution. Let me know if this doesn't work for you.